# Select the same multiple columns from multiple tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to extract specific columns of data from multiple tables which all have the same columns in a single sql query.

As a long winded method I am using the below query:

```
select application, service, serviceid, item
from table10_01
where service IN ('SERVICE12','SERVICE204') and application = 'My Application'
union
select application, service, serviceid, item
from table10_02
where service IN ('SERVICE12','SERVICE204') and application = 'My Application';
```

Is there a way I can use the table names available in the `information_schema.tables` to go through all tables? So where I can just select table wildcard like `table10_%` in one select query?

I understand i can script this query into a for loop but i was hoping to make the select query directly.

thanks you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not possible with regular SQL. You can either use [PL/pgSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-structure.html) or do it in a loop with the programming language you're using.

You can refer to this [link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44729/to-select-from-all-tables-inside-the-schema-in-postgresql), there's an example of some functions written in PL/pgSQL to select from all tables.